# Why would set view.layer.contents instead of using an UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimageview, core-image

Recently I encountered this code:-

```
self.view.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"img_bg.png"].CGImage;
```

This setup a background for the whole view of a `UIViewController`.

Usually, I would just set an `UIImageView` as subview, taking the whole area of the view from the `UIViewController`

Why would someone use one technique rather than an other ?

I found this one a bit disturbing because the background does not show in the storyboard; where I expect it.

Answer (score 1):

that's a great question. Deeply, you are asking the different between View and Layer, you know we can think view as layer's delegate which can handle user's interaction with app or system. when there is no any interaction but render view, we can just use layer, that will take up less memory compared with the view。

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"img_bg.png"))
```

Hope this will help
Cheers

Comment: Sorry this is not what I asked. Both code works fine; I just want to know the differences.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:-

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
UIImage(named: "img_bg.png")?.drawInRect(self.view.bounds)
let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
```

Hope this helps,
Thanks

Comment: Sorry this is not what I asked. Both code works fine; I just want to know the differences.